# MAAS post installation problem. Internal server problem

Tags: installation, maas

I wanted to try [MAAS](http://maas.ubuntu.com) out so I installed the server in VirtualBox VM.  After installation completion, nothing seemed to happen.  I got "Internal server problem" when I tried accessing xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MAAS.  I already update and ran `sudo maas createsuperuser` but nothing seemed to change.

Looking at Apache2 log I found a lot of python error.  At the end of the stack is

> DBUSException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.FileInvalid: Cannot do system-bus activation with no-user.

Comment: @mateo_salta MAAS is ubuntu related.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had this problem too. In my setup it's the avahi-daemon that don't starts at boot. After `sudo service avahi-daemon start` everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using VMware vSphere 5.0. I solved it by installing `build-essential`, `linux source` and VMware Tools.